# Apache (Ubuntu) Virtual host stopped working after upgrade->restart

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

I have a simple webserver with a single virtual host.

Domain name have been changed to local.com

After running

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade
```

the virtual host is now returning the default website 000-default.conf

The log entries goes to `/var/log/apache2/access.log` and `error.log` but no errors.

There's no error when restarting apache2 or with these commands:

```
root@netcon:/etc/apache2/sites-available# apache2ctl -t
Syntax OK
root@netcon:/etc/apache2/sites-available# apache2ctl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server netcon.local.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost netcon.local.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost netcon.local.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/netcon.local.com.conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
root@netcon:/etc/apache2/sites-available#
```

There's only one virtual host:

```
root@netcon:/etc/apache2/sites-available# ll
total 40
drwxr-xr-x 2 root  root  4096 Apr 26 13:08 ./
drwxr-xr-x 8 root  root  4096 Apr 26 12:57 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root  1332 Mar 19  2016 000-default.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root  6338 Apr  5  2016 default-ssl.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root  2015 Nov 22 12:14 _netcon.gk.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root   815 Apr 26 13:08 netcon.local.com.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root   826 Apr 26 13:07 netcon.local.com.conf~
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root  1391 Mar  3 12:59 netcon.local.com.conf_
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root   814 Apr 26 12:58 netcon.local.com.conf_backup

root@netcon:/etc/apache2/sites-available# cat netcon.local.com.conf
  <VirtualHost *:80>
        # All comments have been removed.
        # See 000-default.conf for default comments.

        # Server configuration
        ServerName netcon.local.com
#        ServerAlias *netcon.local.com

        ServerAdmin it@local.com
        DocumentRoot /data/srv/web/netcon.local.com

        # Directory permissions
        <Directory /data/srv/web/netcon.local.com/>
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
          AllowOverride All
          Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Location /data/srv/web/netcon.local.com/>
          Require all granted
        </Location>

        # Logging
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/netcon.local.com_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/netcon.local.com_access.log combined

  </VirtualHost>
```

I dont know how to troubleshoot from here, any help appreciated.

Comment: Is there anything in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`? Because that is where the actual sites are. Those are usually symbolic links to the real files in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there's the correct files in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled made with a2ensite.

They also work as the command apache2ctl -S shows.

And that was also the command that helped me find the error.

```
root@netcon:/etc/apache2/sites-available# apache2ctl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server netcon.local.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost netcon.local.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost netcon.local.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/netcon.local.com.conf:1)
```

There's two times netcon.local.com and the first one is pointing to 000-default.conf that's why (I guess) the default page is shown.
When I disable the default site with a2dissite my website works.

Why this turns up after an upgrade I don't know; maybe someone can explain it? Hostname = website name?